# How to select polygons from one layer that externally touch the polygons of a second layer?

Tags: arcgis-pro, select-by-location

**Background:**

At 3.2.1, I need to select features from one polygon layer that are:

1. external to a second polygon layer, and
2. touch the second layer

Using the Arcgis Pro *Select by Location* graphic, I am referring to examples I and J:

[image]

I have not found an option that has this granularity.  I have also tested options using the *Invert Spatial Relationship* option, as well as sequentially chaining various options, all without success.

**Question:**

How to select polygons from one layer that externally touch the polygons of a second layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:
Select by location:

**1.) Boundary touches**

[image]

**2.) With active selection - invert Within:**

```
a.) Invert Spatial Relationsship
b.) Relationsship: Within
```

[image]

Howerver I think invert a Relationsship is the key in two steps.

**EDIT 16.Jan. 2024:**

1. Boundrays touches - New selection
2. Within - Remove from the current selection

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but your steps also pick up examples A and B in my screenshot.

Comment: 1.) Boundrays touches - New Selection 2.) Within - Remove from Selection

Comment: I believe Xeppit's answer gives the expected result unless there are other criteria not mentioned in the question.